# Inequality About Symmetric Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x$ be an $n\times1$ vector with each element $0\leq x_i\leq 1$, $G$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix and $\mathbf{1}$ be an $n\times 1$ vector with each element equal to $1$. 
$$\frac{(\mathbf{1}^T x)^2}{\mathbf{1}^T G\mathbf{1}} (\leq or\geq)x^TG^{-1}x$$
Can we say which of the following is smaller? Thanks. Not sure if there is an answer or the conditions are enough, since its a problem coming from math inductions of my ongoing thesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim:

We have $$(\mathbf{1}^Tx)^2 \leq (\mathbf{1}^TG\mathbf{1})(x^TG^{-1}x)$$

Proof:

\begin{align} (\mathbf{1}^Tx)^2&=(\mathbf{1}^TIx)^2\\&=((\mathbf{1}^TG^{1/2})(G^{-1/2}x))^2\\
&=((G^{1/2}\mathbf{1})^T(G^{-1/2}x))^2\\
&\leq (\mathbf{1}^TG\mathbf{1}) (x^TG^{-1}x)\end{align}

by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Note that $(\mathbf{1}^TG\mathbf{1})>0$.

Comment: Thanks, really help. What if the left part is $\frac{1^T x}{1^T G 1}$ and the right part is $1^T G^{-1} x$?

Comment: I don't have a proof yet. but trying some numbers show that  $\frac{1^Tx}{1^TG1} \leq 1^TG^{-1}x$ might be true when $x$ is in between $0$ and $1$, the opposite direction seems to be not true. Also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17480/306553 try to stick to one question per post, asking a new quesiton in a comment reduces your chances that your question is being seen by smarter answerers. It could be a trivial question to them.